# Categories order with get_terms_args not working in 4.7

Tags: terms

This has been working well to order categories in admin views (at post.php, post-new.php, and the admin 'Categories' page, itself):

```
// Order list of categories in admin views
function my_sort_terms( $args ) {
        $args['taxonomies'] = array( 'category' );
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
        $args['orderby'] = 'ID';
        return $args;
}
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'my_sort_terms', 10, 2 );
```

However, when I upgraded to WP 4.7, it stopped working.
I've deactivated plugins.  I tested on a stripped-down test site on 4.6 and 4.7 - same result.  4.7 stops this from working.

I know 4.7 has some changes to the get_terms function.  Please help with any ideas or clues.  I don't want to get bogged down with a plugin to do this.

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38589, so where do you define the code you exposed?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking this, but the above code is at the end of my functions.php file.  In my research, I did see the page you linked, above, but couldn't figure out what update to my code was needed to get things working again. Tx

Comment: That recent update may have some impact. Would you mind somehow to test the your code from some plugin? You may install Hello Dolly and type the your code in there just to check if that would work.

Comment: Very good suggestion to use a plugin to test (as, I believe, plugins load in precedence to functions.php?).  This did not fix the problem, though.  As an exercise, I made the 'orderby' as 'name,' instead of ID ('name' is the default for WP_Term_Query).  Changing 'order' from ASC to DESC has no effect, either.  Is this a bug?

Comment: Should I ask the question, again, as just 'How to order categories by term id' ?

Comment: Have you been able to check what I asked you, kindly? @LeoraDeans

Comment: You may always ask the question, but please the more details you provide the better.